# Combine colums into a nested array

Tags: arrays, ruby

I'm trying to make a nested array out of multiple arrays. I have two arrays like this:

```
cat = ["cat1", "cat2", "cat3"] 
dog = ["dog1", "dog2", "dog3"]
```

Is it possible to make an array like this (with headers `"cats"` and `"dogs"`)?

```
animals = [["cats", "dogs"], ["cat1", "dog1"], ["cat2", "dog2"], ["cat3", "dog3"]]
```

I could do this with some long wired code, but is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: have a look [here](http://apidock.com/ruby/Array/zip)

Comment: You should use the plural form when a variable refers to an array, i.e. `cats` and `dogs`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to keep the header close to its values, you could also use:

```
['cats', *cat].zip(['dogs', *dog])
#=> [["cats", "dogs"], ["cat1", "dog1"], ["cat2", "dog2"], ["cat3", "dog3"]]
```

Comment: The one caveat here that I would mention, is that if the `cat` array has 3 elements and the `dog` array has 10 elements, using `zip` will only zip the first 3 elements of each list.

Comment: @JustinWood, it will actually zip all of them, padding with `nil`s for the shorter array. Anyway, that is irrelevant for this question.

Comment: @ndn TIL we are both half right. in `a.zip(b)`, if `a` is longer than `b`, the array will indeed be padded with `nil`. However, if `b` is longer than `a`, the resulting list will not be padded and will still only be the same length as `a`.

Comment: @JustinWood oh, that is terrible design.

Comment: @JustinWood to put it another way: the receiver determines the size. `a.zip(...)` returns a new array with the same length as `a`, regardless of its arguments.

Comment: @Stefan is this also possible for , for example 4 colums ? :)

Comment: @FroggyFreshh sure, `['foo', *foo].zip(['bar', *bar], ['baz', *baz], ['qux', *qux])`, assuming they all have the same size.

Answer (score 4):

You are looking for [`Array#zip`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Array.html#method-i-zip):

```
[%w(cats dogs), *cats.zip(dogs)]
```

Comment: `cat.zip(dog).unshift %w(cats dogs)` was my favorite one (it was ninja-edited out of the history)

Comment: @Stefan, I find the current version slightly easier to read (header being first). It's bikeshedding at this point anyway (:

Comment: could you explain me what the %w stands for ? and the * in front of cats ? thnx :)

Comment: @FroggyFreshh %w is just a shorter syntax for creating string arrays. `*` is used for array [deconstruction](https://endofline.wordpress.com/2011/01/21/the-strange-ruby-splat/).

Comment: so what I can basicly do is animals = [%w(cats dogs), *cats.zip(dogs)]

Comment: @ndn is there a gem that i have to install to use "zip" since it says i'm using an undefined method ? :)

Comment: @FroggyFreshh nope, no gem. Is `cats` nil by any chance?

Comment: well I just tried it with the example it worked so I guess there is somethign wrong with the arrays i'm tryign to use :) i'l check it out thnx alot for the help!

Comment: @ndn So maybe you could help me a bit more lets say I want this 2 d array now in my terminal I can already do that but because in my column some values are longer than other it doesn't show propperly , do you have a nice trick to make for example fixed colums size ? :) thnx alot in advance

Comment: @FroggyFreshh see [How to interleave arrays of different length in Ruby](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3587227/477037)

Comment: @Stefan its not the size of the array that's the problem its the size of the values that isn't hown nicely for example you have something like this: 
cats dogs
verrybigcat dog1
cat2 dog2

Comment: @FroggyFreshh, do you mind just opening a new question? There is no point trying to condense it in the comments, directed to only two people.

Answer (score 3):

Yes.

```
[cat, dog].transpose.unshift(%w[cats dogs])
```